# How to read a txt file line by line?

Tags: python, readline

My txt file:

`name, city, a, 5`
`name1, city1, b, 18`
`name2, city2, a, 4`

```
def main():
    try:
        with open("actions.txt", "r") as infile:
            lines = infile.readlines()
        a = 20
        aa = 0
        newset = set()
        for line in lines:
            line_1 = line.strip().split(", ")
            if a != 0:
                if line_1[2] == "a" and int(line_1[3]) <= a and aa <= 2:
                    aa += 1
                    a = a - int(line_1[3])
                    newset.add(f"a's: {line_1[0]} \t {line_1[3]}\n")
        print(newset)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        exit(f"File not Found")
```

The program needs to read the txt file and make some operations only with objects in lines with name "a". I thought that i did everything correct but pycharm outputs nothing

Comment: Where do you call your `main()` function?

Comment: def main() is the 1 line in my code

Comment: @yanbraginQ that's not what he means. defining main() as a function does not make it run. You need to call main() outside the function. At the end of the file, on the same indent level as `def main()`, call `main()`.

Comment: yep, it works when i add `if __name__ == "__main__": `
    main()